# Opencart add product option to cart

Tags: opencart

I have a custom module I have built based on the featured products, where I can add products to the homepage module, but mine includes the options for the product e.g. colour etc

It displays fine on the site but if I choose an option, it loads the product page instead of adding the product to the cart. If I an a product with no options the add to cart works fine. Any help on how to diagnose and fix the issue

You can see the site @ http://garethgillman.co.uk/clients/reco/

My code is:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
 <div class="product">
  <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
   </a>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="content">
   <p class="prod-title"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></p>
   <?php if ($product['options']) { ?>
<div class="options" id="option_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
 <?php foreach ($product['options'] as $option) { ?>
  <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
   <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
    <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
     <span class="required">*</span>
    <?php } ?>
    <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
    <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
     <option value="">Select An Option</option>
     <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
      <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
       (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?>
       <?php $op_price = $option_value['price']; ?>
       <?php echo number_format($op_price,2); ?>)                               )
      <?php } ?>
     </option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
   </div>
  <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
    </div>
   <?php } ?>
   <p class="price pull-left">
    <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
     <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
     <span class="price-old">
      <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
     </span><br />
     <span class="price-new">
      <?php echo $product['special']; ?>
     </span>
    <?php } ?>
   </p>
   <!--<p class="buy pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">View</a></p>-->
   <p class="buy pull-right"><input type="button" value="Buy Now" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></p>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue or bug which most of em face. Even I have the same issue in different mode, on loading the page with "www.mysite.com" it will not update products which I'm adding to cart from homepage. Then if I select add to cart on clicking the individual product, which takes me to product selection page.

What I found is, when loading the page we tend to load the site like "www.mysite.com", but if you notice if you select the individual product or navigate from one page to other the webpage changes to "mysite.com" which then allows you to add the product to cart in any page.

If you would like to change your web address from "mysite.com" to "www.mysite.com" just follow these steps.

1. Open `.htaccess.txt`
2. Find this statement

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

   and below it add the code to change from example.com to http://www.example.com/:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]

   RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
   ```